# Show a different filename when opening file with ACTION_VIEW intent on android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-fileprovider

I have a file stored in my App's storage like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapp/files/App files/90210_John_s_Resume.pdf
```

the 90210 at the beginning is a file ID for internal purposes only, and I give the user the option to save this file to Downloads folder, where I remove the 90210 prefix. But I also provide the user to preview the file using ACTION_VIEW intent. This causes an issue where the file name in the previewed app still has the 90210 prefix. Is there a way to overcome this?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", finalFile);//NO I18N
intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileUri.toString()));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Change the name of the file before sending the ACTION_VIEW.  That's the only way to do it.  Since the app on the other side can literally be any app that claims to view PDFs (of which there are thousands), there's no way to coordinate how they all work.  Easiest way to do that is to just not put the id on the filename and hold a mapping of ids to filename somewhere else if the ids are useful to you.

Comment: You may also implement your own ContentProvider, if that is not too much work for you.

Comment: You did not tell which issue such  a prefix causes.

Comment: @blackapps more aesthetic rather than a bug. You dont want internally used IDs on a file accessed by the user